# How to cover all lines of a function with jasmine-karma

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, jasmine2.0

How can I cover all lines of the function below using jasmine?

```
   addUser(): void {
    if (this.validateNewUser()) {

        this.newUser._Job = this.selectedJob;
        this.newUser.PositionId = this.selectedJob.Id;
        this.newUser.Position = this.selectedJob.Value;

        this.newUser._Area = this.selectedArea;
        this.newUser.AreaId = this.selectedArea.Id;
        this.newUser.Area = this.selectedArea.Value;

        this.users.push(this.newUser);
        this.clear();
        this.toastService.open('Usuário incluído com sucesso!', { type: 'success', close: true });
    }
}
```

I am currently trying as follows, but no line is being considered covered:

```
    it('Given_addUser_When_UserStepIsCalled_Then_ExpectToBeCalled', (done) => {
        component.addUser = jasmine.createSpy();           
        component.addUser();
        expect(component.addUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });
```

### EDITED

Now:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4tVK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to check if the method under test (`addUser`) has been called if you explicitly call it. You should however check if the method did what it was supposed to do. You may want to know if the toast gets displayed. Therefore, you could rewrite the test as follows.

```
it('#addUser should display toast', () => {

    // given
    spyOn(toastService, 'open');

    // when
    component.addUser();

    // then
    expect(toastService.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Cool, it worked on some lines but not for all, as I could cover all, I sent the photo of how it was in the question

Comment: Apparently `this.validateNewUser()` returns `false`, it's up to you to find out about the reason.

Comment: can you help with a another function that return a promise ?

Comment: `@ Guilherme Prado`: Please post a new question for the new issue.

Comment: @ uminder , i posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306897/how-can-i-coverage-a-promise-response-with-jasmine-and-karma