# How can i coverage a promise response with Jasmine and Karma

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, jasmine2.0

I have a function that returns and treats a promise, I need to cover the return that is inside `then` but I don't know how I can do this, I'm currently trying as follows:

```
    confirmRemoveUser(user: IUser) {
    this.modalService
        .open('Confirma a exclusão do usuário selecionado?', {
            titleText: 'Confirmando exclusão',
            confirmButtonText: 'Sim',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            closeButtonText: 'Fechar',
            buttonType: 'danger'
        })
        .result.then(
            (result: BentoModalConfirmationCloseReason) => {
                if (result === BentoModalConfirmationCloseReason.Confirm) {
                    if (this.removeUser(user)) {
                        this.toastService.open('Usuário excluído com sucesso!', { type: 'success', close: true });
                    } else {
                        this.toastService.open('Falha ao excluir o usuário!', { type: 'warning', close: true, duration: 0 });
                    }
                }
            }
        );
}
```

I'm currently using `callthrough ()` and imagine that with some parameter I can get the promise but I don't know how:

```
   it('Given_ConfirmRemoveUser_When_UserStepIsCalled_Then_UserIsRemoved', (done) => {

        component.selectedJob = {
        };

        component.selectedArea = {
        };

        component.users = [{
        }];

        spyOn(modalService, 'open').withArgs('This is modal msg').and.callThrough();

        component.confirmRemoveUser(component.users[0]);

        expect(modalService.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });
```

And my coverage is like the image below:

[Image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3HSP.png)

### UPDATE

[New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMtLK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test should work when it is rewritten as follows:

```
it('Given_ConfirmRemoveUser_When_UserStepIsCalled_Then_UserIsRemoved', (done) => {
    spyOn(modalService, 'open').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(BentoModalConfirmationCloseReason.Confirm));
    spyOn(toastService, 'open').and.stub();

    component.confirmRemoveUser(component.users[0])
      .then(r => {
        expect(toastService.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
      })
      .catch(e => fail(e));
});
```

You probably also want to know what will be displayed in the toast. Therefore it makes sense to rather use `expect(toastService.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(?);`.

**UPDATE**
Above solution only works if `confirmRemoveUser` would return a `Promise`.

```
confirmRemoveUser(user: IUser) {
    return this.modalService
    ...
```

In your case, the use of the `done` function does not make sense. You need to use `async` and `await`.

```
it('Given_ConfirmRemoveUser_When_UserStepIsCalled_Then_UserIsRemoved', async () => {
    spyOn(modalService, 'open').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(BentoModalConfirmationCloseReason.Confirm));
    spyOn(toastService, 'open').and.stub();

    await component.confirmRemoveUser(component.users[0]);

    expect(toastService.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The same can be achieved with `fakeAsync` and `flush`.

```
import { fakeAsync, flush } from '@angular/core/testing';
...
it('Given_ConfirmRemoveUser_When_UserStepIsCalled_Then_UserIsRemoved', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(modalService, 'open').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(BentoModalConfirmationCloseReason.Confirm));
    spyOn(toastService, 'open').and.stub();

    component.confirmRemoveUser(component.users[0]);
    flush();

    expect(toastService.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Comment: looks good but I'm having the following error message `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'`

Comment: I didn't notice that `confirmRemoveUser ` doesn't return a `Promise`, please check the updated answer.

Comment: I tried the 3 solutions, but all have this error message: `Cannot read property 'result' of undefined`.
I think that's why I didn't call modalService so the result is null, as I could call modalService.Open so that it gives me a result for toast to use it?

Comment: @Guilherme Prado: The reason is that the `modalService.open` `spy` should return `BentoModalConfirmationCloseReason`. I don't know this `class` or `interface` but will adapted my answer making a guess.

Comment: is giving the error that updates in the question, but thank you very much for helping with this I can try some things, thanks